# Strange Output Encoding in WSL

Tags: c++, linux, cross-platform, windows-subsystem-for-linux, portable-applications

I have created a program in C++ which uses wstring. The program is something like this:-

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
const wstring NAME = L"STACKOVERFLOW";
int main()
{
    wcout<<NAME;
}
```

Now, I have tried this program in windows and linux. The program is working on both platform correctly with output as `STACKOVERFLOW` but while using in wsl(Ubuntu), the output is very strange. It is something like this:-

```
 ?????r????????????????
```

**I have two questions now**:-

1. Is this error related to Unicode? because I know that Windows have UTF-16 and Linux has UTF-32 for wchar whereas Wsl uses UTF-8.
2. If it is related to Unicode, then how is it possible that it can work on Windows and linux but not in wsl since Windows and Linux have diffrent encoding.

**P.S.:- If anybody has any idea, please do write your views.**

**Update:-**

Recently, added a new line in the code and the output is like this now(in wsl):-

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
const wstring NAME = L"STACKOVERFLOW";
int main()
{
  cout<<"Hello"<<endl; //outputting hello along with the widestring
  wcout<<NAME;
}
```

and Now, The output is changed to this:-

```
Hello
SAKVRLW��pH�� �0�`� (�$p
```

Comment: Which compiler are you using to compile the program?

Comment: @MarkRansom I am using clang to compile

Comment: You might try adding `endl` on the `wcout` line too.

Comment: Try `_setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT);` before `std::wcout`. Set `LANG=en_US.UTF-8` or `en_US.UTF-16` for the terminal.

Comment: Are you running this in the IDE, bash, cmd, or PowerShell?